# External Hard Drive Can't access Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, external-hard-drive, ubuntu-14.04

I can't access external hard drive connected via usb on my laptop. OS is ubuntu 14.04.

`dmesg | tail -n 20` outputs is below.

```
[  153.014931] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  153.014986] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[  153.014995] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  153.015387] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
[  153.015395] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[  153.015400] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  153.015403] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[  153.015456] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[  153.015462] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  153.015469] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[  153.259237] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  153.278397] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=3940
[  153.278406] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  153.278411] usb 4-2: Product: Passport 0740
[  153.278415] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: WD MY
[  153.278419] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 30303030303030303030303030303030
[  153.387560] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  153.387833] scsi8 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[  154.389598] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD MY    Passport 0740    0203 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  154.390220] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Is the drive formatted, and readable on another computer/OS? I'm not seeing any "sdc: sdc1" messages about any partitions. What does `lsblk` &/or `blkid` &/or `parted -l` &/or `fdisk -l` say? (probably need `sudo`/# for most of them)

Comment: Drive work on Windows.`lsblk`,`blkid`,`parted -l` and `fdisk -l` only give details about hard drive on my laptop. Above commands not gives any details about external hard drive.

Comment: If it doesn't show up at all with those tools, then it's not an easy `mount` command that will get it working. [This Linux Mint](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=172889) (it's Ubuntu-based, well except for LMDE) post has a post or two where the same drive is not detected either, one mentions it may just happen with some *"combination OS+motherboard+Western Digital+usb3"*...